# Alarm javascript, change the sound

Tags: javascript, html, web

My code should work but i guess i made i mistake somewhere, i'm trying to change the sound of an alarm, it's actually working but :
If i'm trying to change the sound of the alarm x and an alarm x+1 has already been add, the sound of x won't change anymore.

It means my code only change the value of the last alarm but i don't know why.

Here is my HTML and my JS, i hope you'll have an answer.`

```js
(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    var temps = new Date();
    var h = temps.getHours();
    var m = temps.getMinutes();
    var s = temps.getSeconds();

    if(h < 10) {
      h = "0" + h;
    }
    if (m < 10) {
      m = "0" + m;
    }
    if (s < 10) {
      s = "0" + s;
    }

    document.getElementById("heure").textContent = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  },1000);


  var i = 1;
  document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener('click', function() {
    //Ajout
    var cp = document.getElementById("ligne").cloneNode(true);
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("id", "num" + i);
    var liste = document.getElementById("liste");
    liste.appendChild(div);
    liste.appendChild(cp);
    document.querySelector("#liste #num" + i + " + #ligne").hidden = false;

    //Suppression
    var l_sup = document.querySelector("#liste #num" + i + " + #ligne");
    var l2_sup = document.querySelector("#num" + i);
    document.querySelector("#num" + i + " + #ligne #del").addEventListener('click', function() {
      l_sup.parentNode.removeChild(l_sup);
      l2_sup.parentNode.removeChild(l2_sup);
    });

    audio = document.querySelector("#num" + i + " + #ligne #audio");
    select = document.querySelector("#num" + i + " + #ligne #son");
    document.querySelector("#num" + i + " + #ligne #son").addEventListener("click", function(){

      value = select.value;
      audio.setAttribute("src", value);
    });
    i++;
  });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Il est : <span id = "heure"></span></p>
  <div id = "liste">
    <div hidden id="ligne">
      <input checked type="checkbox" id="cb"/>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Heures" name="h" id="h"/>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Minutes" name="m" id="m"/>
      <input type="text" name="desc" placeholder="Nom de l'alarme" id="desc"/>

      <select id="son"/>
        <option value="Trance.mp3" id="son1">Trance</option>
        <option value="Classic.mp3" id="son2">Classic</option>
        <option value="Dubstep.mp3" id="son3">Dubstep</option>
      </select>
      <audio controls loop id="audio" src = "Trance.mp3"></audio>
      <button id="del">Supprimer</button>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="plus">Ajouter</button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: For starters, make sure you don't have two elements with same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem is in this piece of code inside `click` listener of `<select>`.

```
value = select.value;  
audio.setAttribute("src", value);
```

As `select` and `audio` variable will always have the value of **last added element**. So it will always make changes to last `<audio>` element. So we need to get the `select` and `audio` from the `this` object inside the `<select>` `click` listener. `this.nextElementSibling` will give us the `<audio>` placed next to `<select>` on which the `click` event is fired :

```
value = this.value;  // for getting value of current select element
this.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("src", value);  // for getting audio element next to current select element
```

**Sample Working Code:**

```js
(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    var temps = new Date();
    var h = temps.getHours();
    var m = temps.getMinutes();
    var s = temps.getSeconds();

    if(h < 10) {
      h = "0" + h;
    }
    if (m < 10) {
      m = "0" + m;
    }
    if (s < 10) {
      s = "0" + s;
    }

    document.getElementById("heure").textContent = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  },1000);


  var i = 1;
  document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener('click', function() {
    //Ajout
    var cp = document.getElementById("num0").cloneNode(true);
    cp.setAttribute("id", "num" + i);
    var liste = document.getElementById("liste");
    liste.appendChild(cp);
    document.querySelector("#liste #num" + i).hidden = false;

    //Suppression
    var l_sup = document.querySelector("#liste #num" + i);
    var l2_sup = document.querySelector("#num" + i);
    document.querySelector("#num" + i + " button").addEventListener('click', function() {
      l_sup.parentNode.removeChild(l_sup);
      l2_sup.parentNode.removeChild(l2_sup);
    });

    audio = document.querySelector("#num" + i + " audio");
    select = document.querySelector("#num" + i + " select");
    document.querySelector("#num" + i + " select").addEventListener("click", function(){

      value = this.value;
      this.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("src", value);
    });
    i++;
  });
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Il est : <span id = "heure"></span></p>
  <div id = "liste">
    <div hidden id="num0">
      <input checked type="checkbox" id="cb"/>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Heures" name="h" id="h"/>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Minutes" name="m" id="m"/>
      <input type="text" name="desc" placeholder="Nom de l'alarme" id="desc"/>

      <select/>
        <option value="Trance.mp3">Trance</option>
        <option value="Classic.mp3">Classic</option>
        <option value="Dubstep.mp3">Dubstep</option>
      </select>
      <audio controls loop src = "Trance.mp3"></audio>
      <button>Supprimer</button>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="plus">Ajouter</button>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

P.S.: As Brahma Dev commented, **id** should always be **unique**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `click` event to update `audio` src. Use `change` event. Then audio should change fluently.

```
  document.querySelector("#num" + i + " + #ligne #son").addEventListener("change", function(){
    value = select.value;
    audio.setAttribute("src", value);
  });
```

Here is a working JSbin https://jsbin.com/ficodot/edit?html,js,output